What causes the JVM heap to grow continuously in a Flink Application
I have A flink application that receives about 50 million records a day that contains updates to prior records. To dedup and keep the latest records, i store the unique keys and latest values in a MapState(5 million unique keys). Every hour a timer kicks off an aggregation of the values in the mapstate.
The key itself is composed of 5 string values of about 10 characters each.
Once data arrives for the next day, the map state is wiped out.
For some reason the application heap keeps growing until it eventually runs out of memory (~300 Gb). Any pointers on what might be going on here and/how to debug.
We have confirmed that the map stae is getting updated as expected.

This question is similar to: How to find a Java Memory Leak. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.20/docs/ops/state/state_backends/, which state backend are you using? If nothing else is configured, the system will use the HashMapStateBackend. It stores data in memory.
